# Custom Buttons in BlackBerry Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, blackberry-playbook

I'm using AIR to develop apps for the BlackBerry PlayBook, and I need to create custom buttons with a gradient, and a different gradient when pressed. The text should be black or white according to the needs (decided by me for different parts of the app).

So is there any way I can achieve this kind of button?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I didn't know that RIM acquired Adobe?!  :p

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 They didn't, the PlayBook apps can be developed in either C/C++, Adobe Flash Builder using BB plugin or RIM's WebWorks SDK.

Comment: @Roshnal not totally familiar with the Playbook AIR SDK. Are you using Flex?

Comment: @f-a Yeah I'm using Flex + ActionScript3. And Adobe Flash Builder as the IDE.

Comment: @Roshnal check this out http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSA95C9644-B650-4783-B5C0-D2C7F95A23E3.html

Answer (score 1):

well...

1. you could programatically create the button gradient with the drawing API or create and embed bitmaps for each state.
2. you could then create a custom button class consisting of the gradient asset and textField object as children with mouse / touch events to control the visual changes and to dispatch a button custom event.
3. finally, you could create a custom button event.

Comment: Can you please give me a code sample for the easiest method? Sorry I'm completely new to BB development in AIR.

Comment: this is not specific to development on the PlayBook.  it's elementary ActionScript programming.  i suggest you learn AS3.

Comment: I was thinking of learning AS3 progressively while doing PlayBook development, and thought it wouldn't be hard as I already have much experience in Java, Python and C++ development.

Comment: it's difficult to learn AS3 from the internet since there are lots of search results from AS2 (which is quite different than AS3) and MXML (unfortunately).  try these 3 book suggestions, you won't be sorry:  1.http://goo.gl/zJvTT (basics)  2. http://goo.gl/Tmeuc (complete-ish) 3. http://goo.gl/icMG5 (fun!)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom [button skin](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/air/apis/qnx/fuse/ui/skins/buttons/package-detail.html) for a [qnx.fuse.ui.buttons.Button](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/air/apis/qnx/fuse/ui/buttons/Button.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spark components buttons , you need to use SkinClass property , in which you can pass any skin object. In this Skin you can set states like up , down , over , disabled.

// code to create a skin class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<!-- host component -->
<fx:Metadata>
    [HostComponent("ImageButton")]
</fx:Metadata>

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<!-- SkinParts
name=labelDisplay, type=spark.core.IDisplayText, required=false
name=iconDisplay, type=spark.primitives.BitmapImage, required=false
-->
<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('add_audio.png')"       includeIn="disabled" />
<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('add_audio.png')"       includeIn="up" />
<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed(add_audio_press.png')"  includeIn="over"/>
<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('add_audio_press.png')" includeIn="down"/>
```

// create a custom button class

```
package
```

{
    import spark.components.Button;

```
public class ImageButton extends Button
{
    public function ImageButton()
    {
        super();
        this.buttonMode=true;
    }
}
```

}

use these two classes like this.

```
<local:ImageButton x="2" y="43" skinClass="skins.audio.Cut" />
```